# How to get C# attribute in the associated XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a C# class like this :

```
public partial class MyClass: UserControl
{
    public String SomeText{get;set;}
    ...

    public MyClass(String Text)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SomeText = Text;
    }

}
```

And I would like to get the attribute `SomeText` in my XAML file. How to do something like this ?

```
<TextBlock Text="{THIS IS HERE I WANT TO HAVE SomeText}"></TextBlock>
```

I am new to C# so I don't know how to do. There must be a simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the `UserControl` element a `Name` and then bind to it as in the example below. If your text isn't going to change you should define it **before** your call to `InitialiseComponent`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="root">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText,ElementName=root}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If your `SomeText` is likely to change then you need to declare it as a `DependencyProperty` instead of a plain old `string` property. This would look something like below:

```
    public string SomeText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SomeTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SomeTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SomeText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SomeText", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
```

You should then change your binding to look like the below, which will cause the UI to update when you change the value of `SomeString`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText,ElementName=root,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: @Pigrou, you're welcome. It's probably useful to know that typing `propdp` and hitting tab twice (once if you have resharper) will generate a lot of the dependency property code for you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a correction:

that is a `Property`[(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), not an `Attribute` [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288059%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), those are 2 completely different concepts.

Second:

WPF has a concept called `DependencyProperties` [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) which you must leverage in order to build complex custom UI controls in WPF.

Third:

There are times when you do not really need to declare properties in your UI. WPF empowers you to separate UI from data via its powerful [DataBinding Engine](http://wpftutorial.net/Databinding.html) and the [MVVM Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel). So, think again whether or not this control you are declaring is the right place to declare your string property.

I suggest you get familiar with all these concepts if you're going to work in WPF.

Give me more details about what you're trying to do and I can give you more insight.

**Edit:**

Basically what you need to do is to declare a `DependencyProperty` in your control like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayName", typeof(string), typeof(mycontrol));

public string DisplayName
{
    get { return GetValue(DisplayNameProperty).ToString(); }
    set { SetValue(DisplayNameProperty, value); }
}
```

Then, in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"/>
```

Please keep in mind that WPF requires a completely different mindset from other frameworks, so my suggestion still stands: get familiar with MVVM and Databinding if you're planning to seriously work in WPF.

Comment: This does not answer the question; despite its length it should have probably been a comment.

Comment: Maybe it does not answer but it clarified some concepts, so HigCore thanks anyway for writing this !